# CSS: how can I make this table fit the border when resized?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the table with the three images fit inside the border when the page is resized (using <kbd>CTRL +</kbd> in the browser), so it looks like this:

[alt text http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/8224/gooddq.png](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/8224/gooddq.png)

And not like this:

[alt text http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/2972/bady.png](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/2972/bady.png)

**How do I do this?**

This is the body and table CSS code:

```
 body {
         background-color: #CC7722;
         margin-left:20%;
         margin-right:20%;
         border:3px dotted gray;
         padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
         font-family:sans-serif;

    }

    tabla {
          width=303px;
          height=123px;

    }
```

Here's the full html file:

```
<html>

 <head>

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
         content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

    <title>Evaluaci&oacute;n de Curso</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
         background-color: #CC7722;
         margin-left:20%;
         margin-right:20%;
         border:3px dotted gray;
         padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
         font-family:sans-serif;

    }

    tabla {
          width=303px;
          height=123px;

    }

     </style>

 </head>

<body>
<form>


<!--img src='http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/4338/softrain2.jpg' width="408" height="123"border='0'/-->

<div-class="tabla">
<table>
<tr>

<td>
<img src='http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/4338/softrain2.jpg' width="300" height="123"border='0'/>
</td>

<td>
<img src='http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/671/oportuniti.png' width="300" height="123"border='0'/>
</td>

<td>
<img src='http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/4852/easytest.png' width="300" height="123" border='0'/>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>









<h1>Evaluaci&oacute;n</h1>


<p>Por favor, tome unos minutos para llenar esta evaluaci&oacute;n. </p>

<p> </p>

<form action="http://localhost/aplicacion.php" method="POST">

    <p> 

        <!--h3>Info Personal</h3-->
        <table>


        <tr><td>Nombre y Apellido:</td> <td> <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" /> </td></tr>


        <tr><td>Empresa:</td> <td> <input type="text" name="empresa" value="" /> </td></tr>

        <tr><td>E-mail:</td> <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" cols="234" /> </td></tr>

       </table> 




        <h2>Curso</h2>

       <table> 
       <tr>
        <td>Nombre del Curso:</td> 
        <td>
        <select name="cursos">
          <option value="NA"></option>

          <option value="AdminLinux">Administraci&oacute;n Linux</option>
          <option value="AJAX">AJAX</option>
          <option value="Cmasmas">C++</option>
          <option value="Cisco">Cisco</option>
          <option value="DisenioWeb">Dise&ntilde;o Web</option>
          <option value="SCJP">SCJP</option>
          <option value="J2EE">J2EE</option>
          <option value="JavaFundamentals">Java Fundamentals</option>
          <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
          <option value="JSPServlets">JSPs y Servlets</option>
          <option value="MySQL">MySQL</option>
          <option value="SCWCD">SCWCD</option>

           <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
           <option value="Photoshop">Photoshop</option>
           <option value="PostgreSQL">PostgreSQL</option>
           <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option> 
           <option value="XML">XML</option>

          </select>

       </td>
       </tr>



        <td>Nombre del Instructor:</td> 
        <td>
        <select name="intructores">
           <option value="NA"></option>
          <option value="Antonio Rueda">Antonio Rueda</option>
          <option value="Jos&eacute; Julio Garagorry">Jos&eacute; Julio Garagorry</option>
          <option value="Carlos Forero">Carlos Forero</option>
          <option value="Daniel Garagorry">Daniel Garagorry</option>
        </select>
        </td>
         </tr>
         </table>

        <div>
    <h2>Valoraci&oacute;n Global del Curso</h2>



        <table>
        <p></p>
         &#191;El curso respondi&oacute; a sus expectativas iniciales? <br />
        &nbsp; &nbsp; Nada(1) / Totalmente(10)<br />
         &nbsp;
         1 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="respondioExpectativasIniciales" value="10" />

        </table>

        <table>
        <p></p>
         Duraci&oacute;n del curso <br />
        &nbsp; &nbsp; Muy Corta(1) / Excesiva(10) / Ideal (5)<br />
         &nbsp;
         1 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="duracionDelCurso" value="10" />

        </table>

<p></p>
<table>
<p></p>
         <b>&#191;Qu&eacute; opini&oacute;n le mereci&oacute; el contenido general del curso?</b><br />

         &nbsp; &nbsp;Deficiente(1) / Excelente(10)<br />


         &nbsp;1 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="opinionContenido" value="10" />

      </table>


        <h2>Evaluaci&oacute;n al Profesor</h2>
        <p>Califique del 1 al 10 las siguientes aptitudes del profesor. <br />&nbsp; &nbsp;<b>Deficiente(1) / Excelente(10)</b>.</p>

        <table>
        <tr><td>Claridad Expositiva</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="claridadExpositoria" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table> 
        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Capacidad de Motivaci&oacute;n</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="capacidadDeMotivacion" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table> 

        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Dominio de m&eacute;todos de ense&ntilde;anza</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDeMetodosDeEnsenianza" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table> 

        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Dominio del contenido</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="dominioDelContenido" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table> 

        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr><td><b>Evaluaci&oacute;n general al profesor</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="evaluacionGralProfesor" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table> 


       <h2>Ambiente del Curso y Materiales</h2> 

        <table>
        <tr><td>Calidad de la infraestructura</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadInfraestructura" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table> 

        <!--p></p>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Higiene de la infraestructura</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="higiene" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table--> 

        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Calidad de los refrigerios</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="10" />
         No hubo <input type="checkbox" name="refrigerios" value="noHubo" />
        </td></tr>
        </table>  

        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Calidad y nivel de los materiales del curso</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="calidadMateriales" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table> 


        <p></p>
        <table>
        <tr><td><b>Nivel de organizaci&oacute;n del curso</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td> 1 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="1" /> 
         2 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="2" />
         3 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="3" /> 
         4 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="4" />
         5 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="5" />
         6 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="6" />
         7 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="7" />
         8 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="8" />
         9 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="9" />
         10 <input type="checkbox" name="nivelOrganizacion" value="10" />
        </td></tr>
        </table>  



        <div>
        <h2>Otros Cursos</h2>
        <p>Marque otros cursos de capacitaci&oacute;n profesional que le interesen.</p>

        <p>
        <table>

<tr><td><label><b>Desarrollo</b></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label><b>Bases de Datos</b></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label><b>Redes y Seguridad</b></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label><b>Ofim&aacute;tica</b></b></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>       




         <tr><td><label>AJAX</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="AJAX"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>MySQL</label> </td><td>  <input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="MySQL"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Cisco</label> </td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Cisco"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Office 2007</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Office2007"></td>
        </tr>

         <tr><td><label>C#</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="C#"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Oracle</label></td> <td> <input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Oracle"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Linux(Redes)</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="LinuxRedes"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Office 2010</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Office2010"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td><label>C++</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Cmasmas"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>PostgreSQL</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="PostgreSQL"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Linux(Seguridad)</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="LinuxSeguridad"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>OpenOffice</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="OpenOffice"></td>
        </tr>

<tr><td><label>HTML y CSS</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="HTMLCSS"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>SQL Server</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="SQL Server"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Solaris(Redes)</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="SolarisRedes"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Photoshop</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Photoshop"></td>
        </tr>


<tr><td><label>Java</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Java"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Solaris(Seguridad)</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="SolarisSeguridad"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>

<tr><td><label>J2EE</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="J2EE"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Windows(Redes)</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="WindowsRedes"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>

<tr><td><label>JavaScript</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="JavaScript"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label>Windows(Seguridad)</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="WindowsSeguridad"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>


<tr><td><label>.NET</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="dotNet"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>

<tr><td><label>PHP</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="programacionShell[]" value="PHP"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>



<tr><td><label>Programaci&oacute;n Shell</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="programacionShell[]" value="dotNet"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>

<tr><td><label>Ruby</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="programacionShell[]" value="Ruby"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>

<tr><td><label>Visual Basic</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="programacionShell[]" value="Visual Basic"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>

<tr><td><label>XML</label></td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="programacionShell[]" value="XML"></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td> <td>&nbsp;</td> 
             <td><label></label></td> <td></td>
        </tr>



         </table>









         </table>




         </table>





        <!--tr><td>AJAX</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Ajax" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>C++</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Ajax" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Cisco</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Cisco" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Fireworks</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Fireworks" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>J2EE</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="J2EE" /></td></tr>

         <tr><td>HTML & CSS</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="HTML&CSS" /></td></tr>  
         <tr><td>Java (b&aacute;sico)</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Java" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Javascript</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Javascript" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>JSPs y Servlets<td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value = "JSPServlet" /></td></tr>   
        <tr><td>Linux</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Linux" /></td></tr> 
         <tr><td>MySQL</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="MySQL" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Oracle (BD)</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="OracleBD" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Photoshop</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Photoshop" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>PHP</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="PHP" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>PostgreSQL</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="PostgreSQL" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Python</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Python" /></td></tr>

         <tr><td>Ruby</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Ruby" /></td></tr> 
        <tr><td>SCJP</td> <td> <input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="SCJP" /> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>SCWCD</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="SCWCD" /> </td></tr>
         <tr><td>Solaris</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="Solaris" /> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>XML</td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="cursosDeInteres[]" value="XML" /> </td></tr-->





        </table>
        </p> 
        </div> 


        <p></p>
<p>&#191;Le gustar&iacute;a recibir informaci&oacute;n por e-mail cuando ofertemos los cursos de su inter&eacute;s?<br />
          <table>
          <td>S&iacute;</td> <td><input type="radio" name="recibeMailsCursos" value="si" /> </td>
          <td>No</td> <td><input type="radio" name="recibeMailsCursos" value="no" /> </td>
          </table>
        </p>




        <h2>Comentarios</h2> 
         <p>&#191;Qu&eacute; le gust&oacute; del curso? &#191;Qu&eacute; no le gust&oacute;?<br />
            &#191;C&oacute;mo cree que podr&iacute;a mejorarse?
         </p>



<textarea name="comentarios" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
        <p></p>

<p></p>
<p>&#191;Nos permite publicar publicar sus comentarios de experiencia con nosotros en nuestra p&aacute;gina web, web mail, brochure u otro medio?<br />
          <table>
          <td>S&iacute;</td> <td><input type="radio" name="publicar" value="si" /> </td>
          <td>No</td> <td><input type="radio" name="publicar" value="no" /> </td>
          </table>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar Evaluaci&oacute;n"/>



        </p>

    </table>
  </form>





  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Please make sure your HTML and CSS validates first...

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean with "validates", please be more specific.

Comment: Use this: http://validator.w3.org/ to validate the HTML and this: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ to validate the CSS

Comment: Thanks, that seems useful. I have a questions: the html parser returns 73 errors, but excepting the images, I think the page is displaying the fine. What benefit do I get from getting the code the way the parser says?

Comment: Having valid HTML and CSS is a good first step in mitigating any cross-browser rendering errors that might pop up.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to stop styling using empty <p> containers, nbsp's and such, and start using margins and padding. You'll appreciate it later as this is a core web dev/design skill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it and tested it with Firefox.

Here are little instructions:

- set width of columns to (width/height)*(height which you want have images) to be images of same height
- set width of all images in table to 100%
- don't set height of images

And here's changed code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
     background-color: #CC7722;
     margin-left:20%;
     margin-right:20%;
     border:3px dotted gray;
     padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     font-family:sans-serif;

}


.tabla img {
  width:100%;
}

 </style>

    <div class="tabla">
<table>
<tr>

<td width="408">
<img src='http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/4338/softrain2.jpg'  border='0'/>
</td>

<td width="407">
<img src='http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/671/oportuniti.png'  border='0'/>
</td>

<td width="241">
<img src='http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/4852/easytest.png'   border='0'/>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** because it will not work in Chrome:

- set width of columns to (width/height)*(height which you want have images) to be images of same height

Comment: Thanks, but I need the third logo to be of the same height of the other two. Also, I want to ask: what does the asterisk mean on "width=197*"? Why are there three different widths?

Comment: Because logos have different aspect ratios, it's width/height. x* means that colum width be (remaining size of table / total width of all colum with * ) * width of current column. In my test all logos have same height

Comment: In google chrome they have different heights. http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/629/different.png

Comment: try to change ( .tabla img {
        width:100%;
}
) to  ( .tabla img {
        width:100%;
        max-height:120px;
}
)

Comment: no it'll not work, because chrome( as i've tested ) doesn't accept table colum sizes with *, then you can use: <td width="408">
<img src='http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/4338/softrain2.jpg'  border='0'/>
</td>

<td width="407">
<img src='http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/671/oportuniti.png'  border='0'/>
</td>

<td width="241">
<img src='http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/4852/easytest.png'   border='0'/>
</td>

Comment: width = width / height * (height which you want to have), i've selected 122px large height